# Can't connect to Starbucks Wifi?

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, updates

Had this problem earlier this week and after a firmware upgrade it was resolved.

Now I'm getting a different error even after rebooting.  The message on the Starbucks redirect is:

> Error resolving “nmcheck.gnome.org”: Name or service not known

If I try it with a live Ubuntu OS, it logs in fine, so this has something to do with Ubuntu updating the network software.

Comment: Please take everything below UPDATE out of the question, put it in an answer, and save that then click on the checkmark to show others what worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I changed my DNS to use Google DNS, and now it works. Wonder if it has something to do with Starbucks Wifi being offered by Google in general ... ?